# why can't we use webview for remote view in app widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, remoteview

Can somebody help me explain it? or figure out a way to use webview in app widget. 
thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean why cant we use webview to develop the applications in android ? Do you mean it ?

Comment: @Pavandroid No,I just want to make a widget which layout is a webview...and maybe the webview can run a web app.

Answer (score 2):

from the google app widget guide:

> A **RemoteViews** object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support
>   the following layout classes:
>
> ```
> FrameLayout LinearLayout RelativeLayout
> ```
>
> And the following widget classes:
>
> ```
> AnalogClock Button Chronometer ImageButton ImageView ProgressBar
> TextView ViewFlipper ListView GridView StackView AdapterViewFlipper
> ```
>
> **Descendants of these classes are not supported**.

so if we check the code, for example: `TextView`

```
@RemoteView 
public class TextView extends View implements ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {...
```

the `TextView` can be used in widget, has the annotation `@RemoteView`, but the `WebView`:

```
@Widget
public class WebView extends AbsoluteLayout
        implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener,
        ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener {
```

dont have the `@RemoteView`.

hope this can make you understand. -):

Comment: thank you！but can we add @RemoteView in front of WebView,and build the sdk by ourself?

Comment: @HurleyZhang you can of course, but then you will creating an Android fork. And in order to use your WebView capable appwidget its users must have this forked Android installed on their devices

Comment: The launcher app decides which widgets are allowed. Most (all?) launchers rely on the default decision-making code in `RemoteViews.onLoadClass()`, but a custom launcher could conceivably override that logic.